# Dynamic ListView height inside another ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to make a dynamic ListView height inside another ListView. None of the answers here I have come to didn't really answer it. I've made a simple example of what I'm trying to do so you can simply copy and paste it to try it and play with it. I've got problem with sub ListView where I need to make it grow or shrink based on number of items in it (problem commented in program)

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

List<List<bool>> subList = [
  [true, true],
  [true]
];

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      subList[index].add(true);
                    });
                  },
                ),
                title: Text(
                  'item $index',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100, // <--- this needs to be dynamic
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int subIndex) {
                    return TestRow(
                        text: 'sub$subIndex',
                        onRemove: () {
                          setState(() {
                            subList[index].removeAt(subIndex);
                          });
                        });
                  },
                  itemCount: subList[index].length,
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(),
        itemCount: subList.length);
  }
}

class TestRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function onRemove;

  const TestRow({this.onRemove, this.text});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(text),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
            onPressed: onRemove,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

BTW I managed to make a workaround by changing height of container (commented part) to `height: 50.0 * subList[index].length` where 50 is height of sub title. I'm still looking for a proper way of doing it where I wouldn't need to hardcode height of the tile and calculate it

Here is video of the project with workaround how it should work

[image]

Comment: can you add a video clip?

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi I don't see a point to create a video of the code above... Simply copy and paste the code in a new project and you'll see what I mean.Whenever you add or remove a new item the size of the sub list view should adjust its size. I'll add video of the project with workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the **shrinkWrap** property to true and remove the container

```
                  ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true, //<-- Here
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int subIndex) {
                      return TestRow(
                          text: 'sub$subIndex',
                          onRemove: () {
                            setState(() {
                              subList[index].removeAt(subIndex);
                            });
                          });
                    },
                    itemCount: subList[index].length,
                  )
```

Output:

[image]